# Adding title above SliverGrid, flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[I need to add the title above the silvergridview, also as grid goes along down I need another title how can i achieve that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtYHZ.png)

Code that i have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shendetimendor_demo/src/commons.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  static Route<dynamic> route() => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Home(),
      );
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                floating: false,
                pinned: false,
                elevation: 4,
                expandedHeight: size.height * 0.35,
                flexibleSpace: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: size.height * 0.35, //035
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35)),
                          color: primary_blue,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/ballina_main.png"))),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
                sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: primary_blue),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
    }
}
```

I need the silvergrid so everything can slide down, the only thing confusing is how can I add some title like header above grid. Is there any library or something, I also did not see any documentation on having titles (headers)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a normal `Text` wrapped inside a [`SliverToBoxAdapter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html) above your grid. This would be just another item of your `CustomScrollView`'s slivers[] property. Something like this:

```
...
...
SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Text('YOUR TITLE HERE'),
),
SliverPadding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
        sliver: SliverGrid.count(
...
...
```